# Select count of total products as well as out of stock products from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have to 3 tables: `product`, `product_to_store`, `store`

```
product table
id quantity status
1   1       1
2   0       1
3   0       1
4   23      1

product_to_store table
store_id product_id
1        1
2        2
1        3
2        4

store table
id  name
1   store1
2   store2
```

To find total products I can run query to fetch all products in table product where status of product is enabled.

```
select count(*) from product where status=1

total             name
2              Store 1
2               store 2
```

To find total out of stock products I can run below query after joining all 3 tables and using `group by store_id`:

```
Select count(*) as outofproducts from product where quantity=0;
```

Result come like this:

```
outofproducts     name
1                Store 1
1                store 2
```

But I want combination of above 2 results in single query like below:

```
outofproducts  total  name
1              2      Store 1
1              2      store 2
```

Comment: add  a proper data sample too  and  not only the expected  result  ..

Comment: "But I want combination of above 2 results in single query like below:" what two results i only see one..

Comment: ""To find total products I can run query to fetch all products in table product where status of product is enabled." What query?

Comment: add  your tables schema  .. how the tables are relatated

Comment: @scaisEdge check now. I have added.But it is understood without it also.

Comment: @RaymondNijland check now

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "To find total products I can run query to fetch all products in table product where **status of product is enabled.**" a **correct** MCVE to add to @Strawberry 's comment the example data is missing a status column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use conditional aggregatiopn, i.e. sum/count over conditions:

```
select
  s.name,
  sum(p.quantity > 0) as in_stock,
  sum(p.quantity = 0) as out_of_stock,
  count(*) as total
from store s
join product_to_store ps on ps.store_id = s.id
join product p on p.id = ps.product_id
group by s.name
order by s.name;
```

This makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0. If you don't like it, replace `sum(p.quantity = 0)` with `sum(case when p.quantity = 0 then 1 else 0 end)` or `count(case when p.quantity = 0 then 1 end)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can start query from store table so that we will get total rows as store table data.
Then use nested query for each store to get out of product and total product count

```
select 
(Select count(*) as outofproducts from product_to_store  ps inner join product p on p.id = ps.product_id where quantity=0 and ps.store_id = s.id  ) as outofproducts ,
(Select count(*) as count from product_to_store  ps inner join product p on p.id = ps.product_id where ps.store_id = s.id  ) as totalCount,
s.name
from store  s
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution also worked but using multiple select queries and fetching those results which have 0 total products. I want results as mentioned by @thorsten. Still up voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the related  subquery for count

```
  select t1.name, t1.outofproducts, t2.total
  from(
      select b.id, b.name , count(*) outofproducts 
      from product_to_store c  
      inner join product a on a.id = c.product_id
      inner  join store b on a.id = c.store_id 
      where a.quantity = 0
      group by  b.id, b.name 
  ) t1 
  inner join (
      select  b.id, b.name , count(*) total
      from product_to_store c 
      inner join product a on a.id = c.product_id
      inner  join store b on a.id = c.store_id 
      group by  b.id, b.name

  ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: This query is for fetching all products data. I want count of total product and out of stock products in a single table from single query